# operator== idiosyncrasies between std::variant and std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++

The automatically instantiated `operator==` for my `std::variant<>` interferes with one of its variations, which is a `std::shared_ptr<>`. My actual variant has about 12 different possible alternatives, but to keep it short, here I just show a trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

using VecInt = std::vector<int>;
using VecStr = std::vector<std::string>;
using VarFoo = std::variant<std::monostate,int>;
using VarBar = std::variant<std::monostate,VecStr,VecInt>;
using PtrInt = std::shared_ptr<int>;
using VarBaz = std::variant<std::monostate,PtrInt>;
int main()
{
    VecInt v1{1,2,3};
    VecInt v2{1,2,3};
    std::cout << "v1 == v2 ? " << std::boolalpha << (v1 == v2) << std::endl;
    VecStr v3{"Hello","World"};
    VecStr v4{"Hello","World"};
    std::cout << "v3 == v4 ? " << std::boolalpha << (v3 == v4) << std::endl;
    VarFoo foo1{42};
    VarFoo foo2{42};
    std::cout << "foo1 == foo2 ? " << std::boolalpha << (foo1 == foo2) << std::endl;
    VarBar bar1{VecInt{42,43}};
    VarBar bar2{VecInt{42,43}};
    std::cout << "bar1 == bar2 ? " << std::boolalpha << (bar1 == bar2) << std::endl;
    VarBaz baz1{std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    VarBaz baz2{std::make_shared<int>(42)};
    std::cout << "baz1 == baz2 ? " << std::boolalpha << (baz1 == baz2) << std::endl;
    
   return 0;
}
```

Which produces the output:

> v1 == v2 ? true
> v3 == v4 ? true
> foo1 == foo2 ? true
> bar1 == bar2 ? true
> baz1 == baz2 ? false

The problem being, that the semantics of `std::shared_ptr<>` is to simply compare the pointer, but not go beyond that to compare the values pointed to, while the rest (`std::vector<>, std::variant<>,...`) actually compare values.

Of course, if you just use a single pointer, it might be reasonable to assume, that `operator==()` should only compare the pointer values. But in the context of a variant, this makes no real sense.

Now, with some fictive variant, containing shared pointers, one would have to write ones own override of `operator==()`, but with many variations in it, this becomes cumbersome quickly. The shortcut being to compare the `index()` of the shared pointer entries and give them special handling, while resorting for the other possibilities to the existing `operator==`. But there is the catch:

```
// the standard, e.g. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp
template< class... Types >
constexpr bool operator==( const std::variant<Types...>& v,
                           const std::variant<Types...>& w );
```

The signature of a self written `operator==` for my variant will have the same function signature as the one automatically instantiated from the template in the standard. So, we either get linker errors (and factually cannot do a custom override for variants) or we have some infinite recursions in code like this:

```
#include <variant>
#include <memory>
using DemoVar = std::variant<std::monostate,int,std::shared_ptr<int>>;
constexpr bool operator==(const DemoVar& v, const DemoVar& w) {
  if (v.index() == w.index()) {
    switch (v.index()) {
    case 2:
      // custom shared-pointer value comparison
      // ...
      return <whatever_it_takes>;
    default:
      return v == w; // bad idea! infinite recursion! Conundrum! No way to differ between    
                     // our custom and the automatically instantiated operator==!
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

So, any idea, how to achieve a custom operator== for a variant, without having to type out all the cases? Or should I better not use operator== at all and give the compare function another name entirely?

Comment: There is no bug here - the variants are not equal. One alternative is to make your own operator ==; another alternative to make a derived class of shared_ptr that has a different operator ==

Comment: @user253751 The latter is actually a good idea! But the vectors are also not the same and what else but a pointer to a bunch of values is a vector anyway? So, the semantics of == is interpreted differently in both cases.

Comment: The semantics are whatever the person who writes the class wants them to be.

Comment: @user253751 Right, only in this case, maybe they should not have written it at all, because they can only be right in 50% of the time.

Comment: not sure what you mean. Equal pointers are pointers to the same thing. That's how pointers works. Meanwhile, equal vectors are vectors with the same contents. That's how vectors work. I suppose the difference is that the thing a pointer points to *isn't* considered part of the pointer. The job of a pointer is to point to something *outside* itself. But you can make your own comparing_shared_ptr which compares the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<T>::operator==` compares the pointers. Thats what it should do (irrespective of being in a `std::variant` or not). If you want to compare the pointees, then you do not want `std::shared_ptr`, at least not a naked one. You can use a custom class:

```
 struct my_shared_int {
     std::shared_ptr<int> value;
     // constructor / copy / move / assignment as desired
     bool operator==(const my_shared_int& other) {
         // compare the pointees
         // (after checking that values arent empty)
     }
 };
```

The generated `std::variant<std::monostate,my_shared_int>::operator==` will then compare the integers not the pointers.

Comment: don't you get an exception if you dereference `value` when the shared pointer is empty?

Comment: @BitTickler right, the actual implementation wasnt the point, I removed it

Comment: Maybe it is a good thing I did not become a lawyer :) Given every other "container" in c++ compares its contents, the "container of one" (yeah I know, there are relics in the API, which would also allow for pointers to arrays), the shared pointer does not (and maybe cannot). So, while I am not happy with the results to my questions on a principal level, this is probably the most pragmatic approach.

Comment: @BitTickler see `shared_ptr` as a container for a pointer, then it makes sense, no? smart pointers try to mimic as much as possible raw pointers, with the difference that they manage the memory

Comment: Yes, but once you try to get "recursive" variants, you need that indirection and then the chain of comparisons is cut short. I would not dare guess, how many pieces of code out there have a related bug, no one has noticed yet :)

Comment: @BitTickler not sure what you mean with "recursive variants", perhaps `std::reference_wrapper` is more like what you want.  https://godbolt.org/z/MPKcx8oEs

Comment: Right - I forgot about that one. Well I used a shared_ptr to a struct, wrapping the type. It should roughly be the same. If reference_wrapper gets the operator== right, that is certainly a good idea.